# Error when reading 'module.xml' of module 'ebx-root-1.0'

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy EBX with Tomcat8 with also a module that I want to test on EBX user interface. After adding necessary `.war` files and libraries I'm getting an error deploying the `ebx-root-1.0`.
These are logs from ebx kernel:

```
2020-06-22 00:44:18,632 CEST INFO   log.setup 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] **** Server Started (logVersion=1.4) ****
2020-06-22 00:44:18,647 CEST INFO   log.frontEnd 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] **** Server Started (logVersion=1.4) ****
2020-06-22 00:44:18,649 CEST INFO   log.frontEnd.incomingRequest 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] **** Server Started (logVersion=1.4) ****
2020-06-22 00:44:18,653 CEST INFO   log.frontEnd.requestHistory 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] **** Server Started (logVersion=1.4) ****
2020-06-22 00:44:18,654 CEST INFO   log.frontEnd.UIComponentInput 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] **** Server Started (logVersion=1.4) ****
2020-06-22 00:44:18,741 CEST WARN   log.kernel 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] Can not initialized JMS environment for reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException > Caused by > java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSException javax.jms.JMSException
2020-06-22 00:44:18,849 CEST INFO   log.kernel 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] Initialized EBX5 core configuration:
-----------------------EBX5 CONFIGURATION-----------------------
  Version du produit EBX5                                : 5.5.1 Fix A [0964:0002] Enterprise Edition
  Fichier de configuration principal EBX5                : default '/WEB-INF/ebx.properties' is file [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ebx\WEB-INF\ebx.properties]
  Démarrage de la VM                                     : 2020/06/22-00:44:18-0309 CEST
  Répertoire racine des journaux                         : C:\ebxLog\
  Répertoire racine EBX5                                 : C:\ebxRepository\
  Répertoire temporaire                                  : C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp\
  Type de persistance du référentiel                     : h2.standalone
  Possession du référentiel                              : unique - 1000 ms
  Fabrique de l'annuaire des utilisateurs                : default
  Seuil de commit                                        : 100
  Seuil pour la validation des messages                  : 0
  Workflow de données activé                             : true
  Service SMTP non activé                                : -
  JMS non activé                                         : -
  Support de HTTPS                                       : true
  URL de servlet HTTP                                    : http://{host}/ebx/
  URL de servlet HTTPS                                   : https://{host}/ebx/
  URL pour les ressources web en HTTP                    : http://{host}/
  URL pour les ressources web en HTTPS                   : https://{host}/
  Localisation des ressources externes                   : inside web apps (directory '/www/')
  Expressions régulières des ressources exclues          : m:CVS/*:
  Locales disponibles EBX5                               : fr_FR
  Locale par défaut EBX5                                 : fr_FR
  Intervalle de vérification des fichiers propriétés (ms): 1000
  Identifiant de VM                                      : 1
  Nom du site                                            : name@domain.com
  Préfixe d'URL des schémas EBX5                         : http://schema.orchestranetworks.com/
  Type de conteneur                                      : servlet container
  Mode EBX5                                              : development
--------------------------SYSTEM CONFIGURATION--------------------------
  Répertoire d'installation de Java     : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241
  Nom du vendeur Java                   : Oracle Corporation
  Version de Java                       : 1.8.0_241
  Nom de la JVM                         : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
  Architecture du système d'exploitation: amd64
  Nom du système d'exploitation         : Windows 10
  Version du système d'exploitation     : 10.0
  Hôte local (IP)                       : ARTIK-PCA32-FKI (10.188.8.88)
  Répertoire de travail utilisateur     : C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
  Répertoire racine utilisateur         : C:\Users\farahk
  Nom du compte utilisateur             : farahk
  Locale par défaut Java                : fr_FR
  ClassPath Java                        : C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin\bootstrap.jar
                                          C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
  Conteneur de Servlet                  : Apache Tomcat/8.5.56
  Version API Servlet                   : 3.1
  JVM - processeurs disponibles         : 4
  JVM - mémoire allouée (Mo)            : 154
  JVM - mémoire utilisée (Mo)           : 59
  JVM - mémoire libre (Mo)              : 95
  JVM - mémoire maximale (Mo)           : 228
------------------------------------------------------------------------

2020-06-22 00:44:18,853 CEST INFO   log.kernel 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] Performance log is not activated
    Performance log is activated by means of property 'ebx.perf.log' in 'ebx.properties'.
    Available operation tokens are: concurrency:csvExport:csvImport:dataService:miscellaneous:tablePagedView:xmlExport:xmlImport.
    Example: 'ebx.perf.log=xmlExport:xmlImport'.
2020-06-22 00:44:19,391 CEST WARN   log.kernel 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] Could not create default repository, it is not yet installed.
2020-06-22 00:44:19,391 CEST WARN   log.kernel 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] Access to web user interface EBX5 to run the installation wizard...
2020-06-22 00:44:19,396 CEST INFO   log.kernel 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] Logs update scheduled at 2020-06-22 00:02:00,393 CEST each day.
2020-06-22 00:44:19,397 CEST INFO   log.kernel 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] END EBX5 initialization.
2020-06-22 00:44:22,475 CEST INFO   log.kernel 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] Modules' registry #56e28857:
    Registered module [ebx-manager].
    Registry now contains: ebx-manager.
2020-06-22 00:44:22,475 CEST ERROR  log.kernel 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] Module [ebx-manager] release 5.7.1 is not a compatible with EBX5 5.5.1.
2020-06-22 00:44:22,485 CEST INFO   log.kernel 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] Modules' registry #56e28857:
    Unregistered module [ebx-manager].
    Registry now contains: .
2020-06-22 00:44:24,748 CEST ERROR  log.kernel 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] An error occurred during module register.
com.onwbp.base.repository.ModuleDefinitionException: Error when reading 'module.xml' of module 'ebx-root-1.0'.
    at com.onwbp.base.repository.Mapper_Module.loadModule(Mapper_Module.java:38)
    at com.onwbp.base.repository.ModulesRegister.b(ModulesRegister.java:10)
    at com.onwbp.base.repository.ModulesRegister.a(ModulesRegister.java:55)
    at com.onwbp.base.repository.ModulesRegister.a(ModulesRegister.java:51)
    at com.onwbp.base.repository.ModulesRegister.a(ModulesRegister.java:54)
    at com.onwbp.base.repository.ModulesRegisterBridge.registerWebApp(ModulesRegisterBridge.java:1)
    at com.orchestranetworks.module.ModuleRegistrationServlet.init(ModuleRegistrationServlet.java:10)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1840)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.onwbp.base.repository.ModuleDefinitionException: The type firstCallDisplay is unknown for the wizard, for the property firstCallDisplay of the bean  in module ebx-root-1.0
    at com.onwbp.base.repository.Mapper_Module_2_0_Abstract.a(Mapper_Module_2_0_Abstract.java:227)
    at com.onwbp.base.repository.Mapper_Module_2_0_Abstract.a(Mapper_Module_2_0_Abstract.java:471)
    at com.onwbp.base.repository.Mapper_Module_2_0_Abstract.a(Mapper_Module_2_0_Abstract.java:260)
    at com.onwbp.base.repository.Mapper_Module_2_0_Abstract.k(Mapper_Module_2_0_Abstract.java:595)
    at com.onwbp.base.repository.Mapper_Module.loadModule(Mapper_Module.java:31)
    ... 22 more

2020-06-22 00:44:29,667 CEST INFO   log.kernel 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] Modules' registry #56e28857:
    Registered module [geo-status].
    Registry now contains: geo-status.
```

I have two ebx libraries versions in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`, I don't know if it's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was the double versioned dependency in the lib folder that was causing the problem. So deleting the wrong one solved this.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need to check all your war files are of same version.
2020-06-22 00:44:22,475 CEST ERROR  log.kernel 0964:0002 [localhost-startStop-1] Module [ebx-manager] release 5.7.1 is not a compatible with EBX5 5.5.1.

You should download correct package and then try again